# How to access the parent of a parent of a partial view's viewmodel?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

In asp.net mvc3, if I have a top view:

```
@model BuilderVM
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TaskSelector", ajaxOpts))
{
}
<div id="here"></div>
```

which gets updated with a partial view in the div `id="here"` returned from the action `TaskSelector` after a post from the Ajax form (i.e. `public action TaskSelector(BuilderVM m){var vm = new SelectorVM();vm.property=m.property;return PartialView(vm);}`. Inside that div, this next partial view is genereated:

```
@model SelectorVM
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Choices", ajaxOpts))
{
}
<div id="selected"></div>
```

From that partial view, the next partial view is then updated inside the div `id="selected"`.

```
@model ChooserVM
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Ender", ajaxOpts))
{
}
<div id="ended"></div>
```

How, from the action "Ender"

```
public ActionResult Ender (ChooserVM vm)
{
 //access BuilderVM.SomeProperty
}
```

can I access BuilderVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you don't. There is no access unless the data is stored in the session.